# MVC Routes data not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller called `BaseController`. In the BaseController, I have an Action method called `Index` which has some logic that involves querying the routes and building the URLs. Something on the lines of:

```
var link = Url.RouteUrl("myroute", new { id = 5 });
```

All this is well and fine until I create a controller `NewController` that extends the BaseController. In the constructor of NewController, I pass BaseController as a dependency.

```
public class NewController
{
  private BaseController _baseController;

  public NewController(BaseController baseController)
  {
    _baseController = baseController;
  }

  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return _baseController.Index();
  }
}
```

Reason why this was needed was because I need to override the view (some HTML and CSS changes). I didn't want to recreate the models and services and rewrite the business logic, so thought this would be the best and most time-effective approach.

Only issue is when the BaseController's Index Action is called, the `Url` is null obviously. Routes data is not available because the request was generated outside the base controller.

What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call action method from another controller. Propably your constructor method gets baseController as a null. can you try to implement it like following

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new BaseController().Index(); // assume you call index action
}
```

Or you can call BaseController action from another controller like following

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Base"); // assume you call index action
}
```

You can also change Route url like following.

```
@Url.RouteUrl("myroute", new { controller = "Base", action = "Index", id = 5 })
```

Comment: Calling the method is not an issue. Routes data is null because the request was generated outside the base controller.

Comment: did you check baseController variable is it null at runtime? and can you share code part which you called BaseController

Comment: did you try to use @Url.RouteUrl("myroute", new { controller = "Base", action = "Index", id = 5 })

Answer (score 0):

Make `BaseController.Index()` virtual:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then use inheritance:

```
public class NewController : BaseController
{
   public override ActionResult Index()
   {
      var index = base.Index();
      //do whatever
      return index;
   }
}
```

Comment: Calling the method is not an issue. Routes data is null because the request was generated outside the base controller.

Comment: Why would you not call the routes data inside the concrete controller?

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution that requires a little bit of code design efforts.

Why don't you **Abstract** your business logic away from the two `Controllers`?

For example: `RouteBuilder.cs` a class that have the functions that contains the logic of building the routes.

And `BaseClass.cs` is a class that contains the Logic shared between the two Controllers.

**Then:**

```
public class BaseController
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {``
      //Instantiase BaseClass.cs and call the needed functions. Then RouteBuilder.cs and call functions.
      return View();
   }
}


public class NewController
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {``
      //Instantiase BaseClass.cs and call the needed functions.
      return View();
   }
}
```

Viola. Problem solved and clean code produced.